# Sync Data between Android Tablet & Phone

Tags: android

I'm looking at creating an Android app and need some advice. I am not an Android developer but I have developed for iOS so I am writing the specification. So I am now trying to figure out the **best way to sync data between Android phone and tablet**?

I am the biggest fan of Firebase around but I'd rather avoid using Firebase or servers if at all possible. Does Google offer an easy way to sync data between google devices using the same google account, via Google Drive on Android?

There's content that will be favorited and pre-existing items (i.e. not user generated or customised content) that need to be checked off in their lists. If those items are removed or favorites are added on the phone for example, that change needs to be replicated on the tablet. What's the best and most cost effective way to implement this? Firebase?

Comment: this question not fit SO at all *best way to sync data between Android phone and tablet* - **primarily opinion-base** ... *How costly could this functionality be?* - **not a programming question** *What's the best and most cost effective way to implement this?* **recomendations are off-topic**
*avoid using servers if at all possible* ... *sync data between the same google devices via Google Drive* ... Google Drive is not using servers, it use telepathy interface ...

Comment: Sounds promising Selvin. You come across any decent documentation on how to go about implementing that?

Comment: It was irony ... Google Drive is using servers ... so you cannot use it and *avoid using servers* at the same time

Comment: Rather than pick holes in the question and trying to be ironic, it's a valid question and one that I think deserves some attention from seasoned developers. I am in need of help and I did mention "if at all possible" regarding avoiding servers, because in my experience they can be costly. I'm simply looking for the simplest solution available, as I couldn't find anything that facilitates this in the Google documentation. If that solution is Firebase or that is Google Drive or indeed something else altogether, great. Just looking for some exploratory help from you veterans.

Comment: I would start from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) ... also it is obvious that you can only "avoid servers" with direct device-to-device connection, and cost of servers depends on amount and frequency of data

Comment: I'd be interested in a (non-ironic) response to this question. I have an app which is writing to a local SQLite database and I want a user to be able to share the data on different devices (and a backup somewhere on the cloud would be a useful byproduct of this). IS Google drive a standard and simple way to do this? - with the user using his/her own Google account?  [Selvin - thanks, but your response to my question isn't particularly required]

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is probably the easiest and cheapest route (ie free).

You can hack together Google Drive to sync user data, but FB will be so much easier.